# Standard URL tries to call a controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I cannot get the following link to open. It tries to call and action instead: controller /action/ www.xyz.com. It should open a new window with the url of a website outside of my application.

```
 @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(@item.WebAddress))
      {
        var url=@item.WebAddress;
        <td><a href="@url">@item.WebAddress</a></td>
       }
```

Comment: What's `@url` and `@item.WebAddress` ?

Comment: try using `http://www.xyz.com` as `href` value

Comment: It is something like www.thevendor.com. URL stored in a database.

Comment: It worked once I added http:// I was avoiding that because some of these will already have http or https.  Thanks Everyone.